# Galaxy tab 2 (gsm) P3100 stuck on start screen after installing clockwork mod recovery. Need help immediately!

Tags: rooting, clockworkmod-recovery, boot

I was following [this tutorial](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_p3100) form wiki.cyanogenmod.org and it went fine till step 12

> #11. Unplug the USB cable from your device You can now manually reboot the phone into ClockworkMod Recovery mode by holding .
>
> #12. The Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 (GSM) now has ClockworkMod Recovery installed. Continue to the
> next section.

And instead of starting in recovery mode, I started in normal mode mistakenly. So I did the whole again. Until now the "Custom binary download" was showing "2 counts" but again mistakenly started in normal mode. Then I did the whole once again, and held the power and up volume button to start in recovery mode. But the device was stuck at start screen (which shows galaxy tab 2 logo). I doesn't even start in normal mode. I did the whole again and again. Now the "Custom binary download" is showing "5 counts".

The device is not starting again neither in recovery mode nor in normal. Please help.

Comment: Did Heimdall show it flashed the recovery properly? Can you boot into Download mode rather than recovery mode and re-flash the recovery?

Comment: @RossC I somehow got my tab started. But when I boot in recovery mode, it opens the default(may be) recovery mode and not the CWM recovery mode though it says device state (I don't remember the exact phrase) as custom(which was not so previously). What to do?

Comment: Ok that's something. Now you have at least a 'panic' option: going to SamMobile and re-flashing the STOCK firmware. Alternatively if you can get into Download Mode (NOT recovery) you could try re-flashing your custom recovery (CWM) again. Be cautious and be careful though. Make a NANDROID backup ASAP so if it all goes wrong you have something to restore. Do you NEED this rooted, is CM worth the risk to you? Is it a stable CM, the nightlies are a parade of bugs and broken parts in my experience. A browse around this site will show you how often CM causes issues.

Comment: @RossC Regarding my case I have a few questions. Should I continue the tutorial now(but I am not getting the CWM recovery mode)? What is I install last stable version of CM? Will that have bugs too? How to do nandroid backup, my tab is not rooted yet(checked using root checker)?

Comment: Few more. "Custom binary download" is showing 5 counts, will that cause problems? How to fix?